# Multi gpu is not working in keras. Getting error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to enable support for multiple gpu training in my model. The code is as follows:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # creating a model
multi_gpu_model = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2, )
multi_gpu_model.compile(loss='cosine_proximity', optimizer='nadam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
try:
    multi_gpu_model.fit_generator(
        sequential_generator('/home/jindal/notebooks/witter_dataset_sequences_20m', batch_size, total_lines), 
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs,callbacks=[WeightsSaver(model, 200)]
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Now when I try to run it, I get an error as follows:

```
creating a partition for /device:CPU:3 which doesn't exist in the list of available devices. Available devices: /device:CPU:0,/device:XLA_CPU:0,/device:XLA_GPU:0,/device:GPU:0,/device:GPU:1,/device:GPU:2,/device:GPU:3.
```

I think that I have read the documentation correctly. My keras package is up to date. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10548) on Github as well. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Note: I am using Jupyter Notebook and have 4 gpus available to me each having 12 GB of Ram. I have limited the Jupyter Notebook to use only 2 GPUs (GPU number 2 and 3) by using the command

```
%env CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID
%env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2, 3
```